# cargo tests running in parallel even though --jobs 1 is specified

Tags: rust-cargo

I'm running tests from the command line via:

```
cargo test --workspace --tests --jobs 1
```

I'm testing a server service, where each tests starts and stops the server and interacts with a service. So, running in parallel will not work. I observe multiple tests trying to start the server at the same time. I've resorted to guarding against this, where I'm observing multiple tests attempting to start the server, with the guard eventually passing when the `owning test` stops the server. My understanding is that the --jobs 1 prevents tests from running in parallel, which is exactly what I want. However, it seems to not be working. Is this a known issue? Have I done something wrong? Or did I misunderstand the usage of --jobs n ?

I can provide more details, that lead me to this conclusion, if needed.

Answer (score 3):

Found that in addition to `--jobs 1` I needed to add `-- --test-threads=1`

Comment: Does that tests multi-threading in your test?